# Can I use an iFrame shim to help Jquery Autocomplete show over an applet Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, applet, jquery-autocomplete

I have a page that has a jquery autocomplete and a Java applet. Due to widely documented issues Java applets do not support Z-Index.

I found [this](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/entry.php?249-A-better-Iframe-Shim) example of an iFrame shim that seems to work. Because JQuery Autocomplete is adding the ul to the dom at runtime I am not sure how to properly shim it.

Does anyone know how to do this? I only need it for Chrome.

Comment: All jQuery-UI widgets [trigger events](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#events) to which you can attach callbacks. Showing your iframe on the `open` event and hiding it on the `close` event should be sufficient.

Comment: Right but since it generates the code and injects it I don't know how to tell it to "inject it into this div". Also I am not sure how to copy the styling info over would I use selectors?

Comment: Without some actual specific code, we can't really help you any further.

Comment: Thats fine, my solution ended up being a little more pragmatic and if it helps anyone I can post it. It involved using overflow scrolling and the location attribute of the autocomplete.